# How handle internet connection change on BIG AyncTask

Tags: android, json, crash

I'm developing an Android application that do a big work in a AsyncTask (can be 5 minutes of AsyncTask activity).

This Task need the internet connection so at the start I check if the device is online or not.

BUT IF the user change connection from wi-fi to mobile connection or go offline  when the GraphRequest is running i got a crash with this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Here is the part of the code where crash:

```
// I Check if the device is online, if yes:

for(j=0; j<n_foto_pub;j++) {

        GraphRequest request2 = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "MY_QUERY",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        try {                                
                            JSONObject obj1 = response.getJSONObject();
                            JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("data1");  <--- CRASH HERE
                            JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject("data2");  
                            int ris = obj3.getInt("ris");                            
                            ..........

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
        request2.executeAndWait();
        }
```

I have a catch but crash anyways.

**How can i avoid the app crash and instead maybe kick the user back on the previous activity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below code , u will get better idea.

```
    @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  {
    try
    {
        //Your operation always inside try catch block to avoid crash.
        for(j=0; j<n_foto_pub;j++) 
        {
           if(checkInternet()) //check internet for each loop
           {

           }
           else
           {
             callBackActivity();
           }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
         callBackActivity();
    }
  }
```

Comment: My loop is really long filled with JSON request so i think there will be high chance of get a crash in any case with this solution.

Comment: first json request inside the try catch block so app never get crash it will get exception only. when exception reached simple call callbackActivity() method. i updated my answer.

Comment: if my answer helpful to you. then accept & upvote. it will help others. Happy Help @GMX

Comment: Seem work... now on the catch i have to kill the AsyncTask, you know how do it? this.stop() seem don't work

Comment: mAsynTask.cancel(true);. it will cancel the task. u will call this in catch block.

Comment: With this i got: Non-static method 'cancel(bolean)' cannot be referenced from a static context